# Single word for a person who gets addicted to a specific food item for a while

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word for a person who gets addicted to a specific food item for a while, and then moves on to other, but is usually binge eating some specific food or the other. Example - My roommate got addicted to some chocolate and got one or two every day for a week, then she left it and got addicted to soup and kept drinking soup instead of breakfast or lunch, three to six packets in a day.

Comment: They have an *addictive personality*?

Comment: A *plain serial eater*, perhaps? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you may dare mint a neologism with the suffix "*-aholic*".

In "*workaholic*" it apparently worked out pretty well but I'm not sure how a word like "*chocolateaholic*" would be welcomed.

Comment: It's usually formed as "chocoholic", actually.  :-)

Comment: So now I finally know what I really am :-)

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, this is called a **fetish**.

*I have a cheeseburger **fetish** right now.*

However, even though **fetish** has a medical [psychiatric, sexual perversion] definition, the medical definition is rarely used in common American speech, unless speaking specifically of the sexual disorder.

So if you want *addicted* to indicate a medical problem rather than an eccentricity, it might be better to use the suffix **-philia**.

*I have "cheeseburger- **philia**". I'm gaining weight like you wouldn't believe.*

Still, this would be an absurdity.

Comment: Fetish is a standalone word. I was not sure whether a specific word for "food fetish" exists or not. Your answer is helpful though. Thanks! :)